# How to create a class dynamically

Tags: c#, dynamic

I need to create a class object dynamically. I attempted this using the dynamic keyword.

```
dynamic dataTransferObject = new dtoClass();
                dataTransferObject.Property1= "someValue";
                dataTransferObject.Property2= "someOtherValue";

                LogicLayer.Update(dataTransferObject);
```

I will interpret the object to perform further action inside of the logic layer. The compiler does not like my syntax, please advise!

Comment: Does dtoClass exist at compile time or only at run time?

Comment: This object will only exist at runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the ExpandoObject to accomplish this.

```
dynamic dataTransferObject = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
dataTransferObject.Property1 = "someValue";
dataTransferObject.Property2 = "someOtherValue";
```

Comment: I'm looking into this now, seems to be what I am after

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you're looking for!

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek6DynamicMalleableEnjoyableExpandoObjectsWithClay.aspx

Go to the section called "Expandos and Dynamic" - it allows you to do the following:

```
var person = New.Person();
person.FirstName = "Louis";
person.LastName = "Dejardin";
```

Stu

Comment: This is great info, I can foresee myself using the ClayFactory, very nice!

Comment: Yeah - it builds on the Expando stuff but gives you a much cleaner syntax. Messing around with it is on my to-do list too.

Answer (score -1):

try to use anonymous type. check following code:

```
var v = new { Property1 = "someValue", Property2 = "someOtherValue" };
```

Anonymous types provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of read-only properties into a single object without having to explicitly define a type first.

Comment: The problem is that this object will be passed to another logical layer, and I am not sure if it will be interpreted correctly?

Comment: maybe it will be better to use interface for this issue

Comment: However, anonymous types are internal and can't pass assembly boundaries.