# Javascript "var obj = new Object" Equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, oop, object, translation

Is there an easy way to create and Object and set properties in C# like you can in Javascript.

Example Javascript:

```
var obj = new Object;

obj.value = 123476;
obj.description = "this is my new object";
obj.mode = 1;
```

Comment: Errm, do you mean creating an object in general or creating an actual `System.Object` and adding properties dynamically?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try c# anonymous classes

```
var obj = new { 
    value = 123475, 
    description = "this is my new object", 
    mode = 1 };
```

there are lots of differences though...

**@Valera Kolupaev** & **@GlennFerrieLive** mentioned another approach with *dynamic* keyword

Answer (score 14):

In case, if you want to create un-tyed object use [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).

```
dynamic employee, manager;

employee = new ExpandoObject();
employee.Name = "John Smith";
employee.Age = 33;

manager = new ExpandoObject();
manager.Name = "Allison Brown";
manager.Age = 42;
manager.TeamSize = 10;
```

Your other option is to use [anonymous class](http://blogesh.wordpress.com/2008/04/19/anonymous-types-in-c-30/) , but this will work for you, only if you would use it in the scope of the method, since the object type information can't be accessed from outside of the method scope.

Answer (score 5):

In C# you could do:

```
var obj = new SomeObject {
    value = 123476,
    description = "this is my new object",
    mode = 1
};
```

EDIT: Holding this here pending clarification from OP as I may have misunderstood his intentions.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is you use C# 4.0 Dynamic types like Expando Object... see this topic:

[How to create a class dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587633/how-to-create-a-class-dynamically/6587659#6587659)