# What's the best way to organize feature files?

Tags: cucumber, tdd, bdd, specflow, gherkin

One challenge I haven't solved yet is organizing my feature files and scenarios in a way, which makes it easy to navigate and explore in Specflow and BDD.

Imagine one year later someone else wants to come along and learn about the system. Where to start? What's most important, what's less important? Any relations between features? Does the system handle a particular scenario? Has the author thought about this problem?

Can anyone share some techniques, reads or tools, which focus on that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This question really is about personal preference, but my answer is how I make my directories easier to understand.

With the projects that I've been working on, I've had to think about problems like this quite a bit. I know that later down the line, other people will look through the cucumber directories to add more or do various pieces of bug fixing.

Generally speaking, we have taken this approach (I'll use our CucumberJS structure as an example):

```
project
|   features
|   |   elements
|   |   |   pages
|   |   |   |   home.js
|   |   |   |   index.js // grab all of the things in the pages directory
|   |   |   |   search.js
|   |   |   index.js // grab everything in elements directory and the index of pages
|   |   |   urls.js
|   |   |   test_customers.js
|   |   feature_files
|   |   |   home
|   |   |   |   homepage_links.feature
|   |   |   |   homepage_accessibility.feature
|   |   |   |   homepage_check_welsh_translation.feature
|   |   |   search
|   |   |   |   search.feature
|   |   |   |   search_security.feature
|   |   step_definitions
|   |   |   common // Won't go into this, but we have a library of reusable steps and functions in here for different projects that we can just port over from git
|   |   |   project
|   |   |   |   pages
|   |   |   |   |   search
|   |   |   |   |   |   search_steps.js
|   |   |   |   |   |   search_security_steps.js
|   |   |   |   |   home
|   |   |   |   |   |   home_steps.js
|   |   |   |   |   |   home_accessibility_steps.js
|   |   |   |   navigation_steps.js
|   |   |   |   login_steps.js
|   |   support
|   |   |   env.js // Timeouts
|   |   |   hooks.js // Setup/Teardown for scenarios
|   |   |   world.js // Setting up the drivers
|   reports
|   |   2017
|   |   |   03
|   |   |   |   05
|   |   |   |   |   report.html
|   |   |   |   |   report.js
|   |   |   |   06
|   |   |   |   |   report.html
|   |   |   |   |   report.js
|   |   |   |   07
|   |   |   |   |   report.html
|   |   |   |   |   report.js
|   |   report.json
|   screenshots
|   |   failed
|   |   |   2017-03-05
|   |   |   |   search_security_xss_204057.png
|   |   |   2017-03-06
|   |   |   |   search_security_xss_100532.png
|   |   |   |   search_security_xss_101054.png
|   |   |   |   search_security_xss_101615.png
|   |   search_security
|   |   |   2017-03-06
|   |   |   |   search_security_xss_100528.png
|   |   |   |   search_security_xss_101050.png
|   |   |   |   search_security_xss_101611.png
|   |   |   |   search_security_xss_101841.png
|   .gitignore
|   README.md
```

Say you're new to a project, so you want to find out what scenarios have been written.
You know it's part of the feature set, so you go down that route, you're looking for the feature file, so you go down that route. You're interested in how the security has been tested for the search feature, so you go into there and locate the file.

It's the same theory throughout the rest of our folder structure. Everything is exactly where you'd expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, that is very helpful. So you achieve order by putting more thought and discipline into folder structure and features breakdown. Features and steps get aligned with software components structure. Feature files are broken down by specific aspects common to scenarios they hold. Step definitions are grouped in files following the feature file names. I suppose this requires certain discipline to keep it all in sync? I'll try the same as part of refactoring.

Comment: It does require discipline, but those on the team appreciate how easy it is to maneuver around the directories.
We also have been attempting to keep our suite as human readable as possible, using JS Objects, and Cucumber Expressions rather than gnarly regexps. Equivalents in C# could be: [underscores](http://specflow.org/documentation/Step-Definition-Styles/) and [ExpandoObjects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625907/javascript-var-obj-new-object-equivalent-in-c-sharp). Human readablity is a great thing to nail, as it leaves less of a gap between new starters and the project experienced.

Comment: You'll also note that there are some instances where you don't have to add a new file. In my example, you can see the `homepage_check_welsh_translation.feature`, but no Welsh translation steps. This in practice happens quite a bit. The steps that I have written in `home_steps.js` - in this case will happily work for the Welsh translation, but as they are technically two different features, I would separate out the feature files.

If I wanted to add a new step that I was only using for the Welsh translation, I would create a new steps file, in that case.

Answer (score 6):

It's a big question and I don't think I have a direct answer, but here are some considerations that have helped us shape our feature files.  A lot of this comes down to preference and the specific needs of the project.

**Feature files are not the same as user stories.**

From [this excellent article](http://blog.mattwynne.net/2010/10/22/features-user-stories/comment-page-1/) from Matt Wynne (author of The Cucumber Book):

> When Aslak created Cucumber, he renamed the files from .story to .feature. This wasn’t an accident or an idle act of whimsy: it’s because there’s a difference.
>
> User Stories are a planning tool. They exist until they’re implemented, and then they disappear, absorbed into the code.
>
> Cucumber features are a communication tool. They describe how the system behaves today, so that if you need to check how it works, you don’t need to read code or go punching buttons on the live system. Organising your features according to the way they were planned and implemented is a distraction from this purpose.

**Writing declarative feature files that are dense with business language might make your scenarios even more discoverable than a perfect directory structure**

As you project grows (and more people start contributing), it becomes more and more difficult to just browse directly to a scenario's location.  The next best thing? Searching for it.  This is easier if you're scenarios are more declarative and less imperative.  From [this article from SauceLabs](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Best+Practice%3A+Imperative+v.+Declarative+Testing+Scenarios):

> Tests should largely focus on what needs to be accomplished, not the details of how it is done. They should mostly be understandable when read by non-developers.

The great thing about compact scenarios written at a higher level of abstraction, is that you can fit more of them into a feature file before it starts to feel crowded.  For system tests, we've had good luck pairing high-level gherkin with the page object pattern, because it provides a layer for all that detail to live.

**Scenarios and features are easier to find if they use the same business language as the UI**

If you have an action called "Remove" in the UI, "Delete" in the test, and "Archive" in the production code, it can be difficult for either developers or business people to find the scenarios associated with that action.  It may be easier to search for the scenario if the test always follows the UI (assuming the average team member using your BDD tool is more familiar with the UI than the source code).

Comment: Being as descriptive as possible is always a good place to start, and will 100% help in the long term. Working with a Page Object Model or Screenplay Pattern are brilliant ways of achieving this with very little effort. With that being said, a good folder structure as a foundation is also a solid way to help someone new who’s exploring the framework, or debugging a broken test, especially if you aren’t using an IDE with the ability to click through a method to open its source

Answer (score -2):

My way is to organize by User Types on Actions on End Points: Application/Page, because fundamentally the test is to examine how each restful API called by whom for what at where/when.

Personally, I also like Robot Framework over Cucumber.