# Multiple Step Definitions match error in Cucumber

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber, yarnpkg, cucumberjs

I recently got started with Cucumber. I am trying to implement Cucumber+Protractor+TypeScript, using this [link](https://github.com/spektrakel-blog/angular-protractor-cucumber) as the baseline.

I am trying to follow this structure, 
    
    `C:.
    |
    ├───.circleci
    |
    ├───.vscode
    |
    ├───e2e
    │   ├───features
    |   |      |--sample.feature
    |   |      |--sample2.feature
    |   |
    │   └───steps
    |   |     |--pageobject1_step.ts
    |   |     |--pageobject2_step.ts
    |   |     |--common_step.ts`

I have a simple feature inside both sample and sample2 feature files. However when I try running the tests, I get

```
 `Given I am on the angular.io site
   Multiple step definitions match:
     /I am on the angular.io site$/ - Yadav\Documents\angular-protractor-cucumber\node_modules\cucumber\src\support_code_library_builder\define_helpers.js:90
     I am on the angular.io site`
```

I read this [link](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/748) which states which makes me believe that this is not recommended. If this is correct, how can I use the power of Page Objects and more importantly, resolve the multiple step definitions issue?

Reproducible example is here in this [GIT](https://github.com/zac11/yarn-cucumber-ts).

Comment: You can make step_definitons independent from page object. Just create a step witch have in logic loading specific website and page object to the variable `this.currentPage` so you will be able to use any pageobject in any step, without duplicating it. Look here is example of framework based on protractor.  https://thesoftwarehouse.github.io/Kakunin/ without typeScript but maybe you gona get a clue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ambiguous error happens when 2 steps share the same regex/string in their step definition, as the runner has to decide which one of them to use.

If there is a shared step between multiple features and scenarios, it's best to separate these into common files, to make them easier to track.

See my answer to the question "[What's the best way to organize feature files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226940/whats-the-best-way-to-organize-feature-files/43231594#43231594)" to see how I organise my projects.

In pseudo-code (the Ruby implementation), I'll give an example.

**Example**

As a tester, you'll want to be able to navigate through the webpages that you have, without expressly stating the URL in the feature file, in the case that the URL changes at some point in the future.

```
urls = Project.urls # Class with url method that returns a map, where pages are the keys and urls are the values

Given 'I navigate to the {string} page' do | page |
    driver.navigate.to(urls[page.downcase])
end
```

This will mean in the feature file, you'll be able to do this:

```
Given I navigate to the "Home" page
```

Which keeps the step dynamic, easily reusable and maintainable for the future, with no need to duplicate the step definition.

**Edit**

In the comments, a working example for the Page Object Model with cucumber has been requested. [Here's a working example on Git](https://github.com/KyleFairns/Ruby-Example-for-Multiple-Step-Definitions-match-error-in-Cucumber).

Written in Ruby, this is an extremely bare-bones version of the framework, denoting directory structure and how I personally work with the POM (note: there are many "right" ways to do this).

This example is a lot stricter with the POM than I suggested to use in the example above, instead storing a "go_to" method within the "urls" file in the elements directory, but as stated previously, there are many "right" ways to go about utilising the POM.

Comment: I kinda get the idea, and your directory structure is what I'm trying to achieve. However I'm not sure how to implement `If there is a shared step between multiple features and scenarios, it's best to separate these into common files.`.

Comment: @demouser123 I’d separate those into a “common” folder within the step definitions folder, with a new file denoting what the steps within do. “steps/common/navigation.ts” would be where I would put the step that I outlined in my answer, for instance, and I would separate ones for each page into the “steps/pages” directory, again in files and folders denoting exactly what the steps within are aiming to test.

Comment: @demouser123 I haven’t done work with typescript before, but if you don’t mind it being in Ruby or plain ol’ JavaScript, to illustrate the point, I’d be happy to

Comment: Shouldn't matter much. I can work with both Ruby and JS.

Comment: @demouser123 See the working example in my edit, feel free to ask any more questions you have after viewing it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156423/discussion-between-demouser123-and-kyle-fairns).