# How to resolve ambiguous problem in cucumberjs?

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I am using protractor-cucumber framework, When going to execute more than file with similar any single step in file both are going to skip and getting error ambiguous step definition.

```
feature 1
Given goto google world
When Send "Mike" to text box
Then verify result should be appear
```

```
feature 2
Given goto google world
When Send "Samp" to text box
Then verify result should be appear
```

```
 config file

     cucumberOpts = {
        require: ['./Test_Scripts/*.js',
            './Support/hooks.js'],
        format: 'json:Reports/results.json',
        strict: true

    }
    suites = [
        '/feature/*.feature'
    ]
```

How to execute both file without ambiguity?

Comment: please show your config

Comment: cucumberOpts = {
 require: ['./Test_Scripts/*.js',
  './Support/hooks.js'],
 format: 'json:Reports/results.json',
 strict: true
 
}
suites = [
 '/feature/*.feature'
]

Comment: Don't you have same steps defined twice somewhere in `./Test_Scripts/` directory?

Comment: yes both file exist in this folder

Comment: I don't mean `*.feature` files. I mean files where you have defined your steps. The error says that your steps in `*.feature` match to more than one regexps in step definition files.

Comment: my concern is how to execute both file without ambiguity? 
it's there any chance in cucumber to check all the step after execute file

Comment: Error 

Multiple step definitions match:
         /^Login as admin $/ - file1.js:8
         /^Login as admin $/ - file2.js:8

Comment: So you have two options: 1. Remove second step definition. 2. Change one of your step definition to have different regexp. ### I strongly recommend 1st option.

Comment: Sorry but can you please give me some example for step 2

Comment: Just remove whole `/^Login as admin $/` from `file2.js`

Comment: is there any chance in cucumber to check all the step after execute file.
might be *guess* keyword for cucumber option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar problem with ambiguous step definition was already elaborated here:
[Multiple Step Definitions match error in Cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664254/multiple-step-definitions-match-error-in-cucumber/46666605#46666605)

Comment: thanks,
i had read but not like to share common step in single file. it's better to something else

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code line in configurations.

```
specs:['./feature/*.feature'],
```