# How do you create and use common feature files in Cucumber?

Tags: javascript, cucumber

I'm using Cucumber to help define some tests I'm working on, however the application is growing larger and I'm in need of a better structure.

```
project
|    feature_files
|    |   app1.js
|    |   app2.js
|    |   app3.js
|    |   ...
|    step_definitions
|    ...
```

All the apps begin their tests in the same way, there's a start page where you enter a variable and click a link. The problem is that Cucumber complains about `multiple step definitions match` because those beginning steps are defined in each feature file.

After some researching it seems this is possible, but I can't find a JavaScript solution on how to implement it. [This solution is in Java](https://medium.com/@bcarunmail/sharing-state-between-cucumber-step-definitions-using-java-and-spring-972bc31117af) and [this SO answer gives a good idea of how to organize my folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226940/whats-the-best-way-to-organize-feature-files/43231594#43231594).

How can I implement a common feature file that can be reused in multiple feature files?

Comment: You should have a single step def and pass the param as per your environment. Please don't create the duplicate step defs.

Comment: @supputuri could you give me an example please? I don't understand what you mean pass the param as per my environment.

Comment: It seems like you are looking for how to organize **step definitions** where they are reused in multiple feature files. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Just move your common steps into a separate step def file and remove any duplicate step implementations (step defs). Cucumber will pick-up the step def from all the files located in your `step_definitions` folder, so it does not matter which file holds the implementation. However it's best practice to maintain the common functionalities in separate step def files.

Let's say you have below 3 steps.

```
Given User navigates to "Application1" url
Given User navigates to "Application2" url
Given User navigates to "Application3" url
```

Now while developing the step defs you don't have to write 3 different implemenations for all of them, instead you have to develop only one step def with the variance as a param as shown below.

Your step def should look something like this

```
Given(/^User navigates to "([^"]*)" url$/), async function(app){
     // your logic goes here
});
```

Now implement the logic to handle different applications in your step def.